# VLOOKUP to check if a value exists in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wildcard, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have data like this in a column:

```
John L. Doe
Jane N. Doe
Michael A. Doe
```

I'm trying to match the entries against another column with this format.

```
doe, jane
doe, john
doe, michael
```

I've tried VLOOKUP's for the lastname and using wildcards:

`VLOOKUP("*" & A1 & "*",B:B,2, FALSE)`

but I'm getting `#N/A` as a result.

Answer (score 1):

If your columns are labelled, then in C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=MATCH(TEXT(MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2)+1,LEN(B2))&"*"&LEFT(B2,FIND(",",B2)-1),"@"),A:A,0)
```

should return the row number of a match in ColumnA for the value in ColumnB that is in the same row as the formula result.

To match "the other way around" is very similar, and as it happens for the example the results the same:

```
  =MATCH(TEXT(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1)+1,LEN(A2))&"*"&LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),"@"),B:B,0)
```